# htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string when I try send email in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I create function for contact form.

I have this code:

```
public function sendContactForm($request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'topic' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'message' => 'required|string',
            'captcha' => 'required|captcha',
            'acceptReg' => 'required|integer',
        ]);
        $adminEmail = $this->frontendRepository->getSystemAdminEmail();

        $title = $request->input('topic');
        $txt = nl2br($request->input('message'));
        $userName = $request->input('name');
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $ip = $request->getClientIp();
        $dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $mailTitle = "Masz wiadomość ze strony". env('APP_NAME')."<br/>";
        $message = "
        <b>Dane wiadomości:</b> $dateTime [$ip]<br/>
        <b>Tytuł wiadomości:</b> $title<br/>
        <b>Imię:</b> $userName<br/>
        <b>Adres email:</b> $email<br/>
        <b>Wiadomość:</b> $txt<br/>";

        Mail::to($adminEmail)->send(new ContactMail($message, $mailTitle, $email, $adminEmail));

        die('mail sent!');

    }
```

ContactMail.php

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ContactMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $message;
    public $title;
    public $sender;
    public $adminMail;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(string $message, string $title, string $sender, string $adminMail)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->title = $title;
        $this->sender = $sender;
        $this->adminMail = $adminMail;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
{
    return $this->subject($this->title)
            ->from($this->sender)
            ->to($this->adminMail)
            ->replyTo($this->sender)
            ->view('mail.contactform', ['message' => $this->message]);
}
```

My contact form.blade.php:

```
@section('content')
    {{ $message  }}
@endsection
```

When I run my script I have error:

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: >/var/www/project/resources/views/mail/contactform.blade.php)

How can I repair it?

Comment: Wait..  you just _completely_ changed the question? **Don't do that!** If the first issue was resolved, either close this question (by posting an answer yourself) or delete it. Then you write a _new_ question with your new issue.

Answer (score 1):

`build()` method of your `Mailable` class is needed to configure your mail object and return self. So remove `->send(..)` call in the end of your call chain:

```
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject($this->title)
            ->from($this->sender)
            ->to($this->adminMail)
            ->replyTo($this->sender)
            ->view('mail.contactform');
}
```

**EDIT:**

> htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: >/var/www/project/resources/views/mail/contactform.blade.php)

The problem lies within your mail template file `contactform.blade.php` - you can't use variable name `$message` in your `Mailable` class because Laravel itself uses it to pass your `Mailable` object to template (so in your template `$message` holds reference to an object, not your message string). So you can think about it as being reserved by the framework.

To fix this rename your `$message` field into something else, for example, `$content` (or `$text`, `$body` and so on) both in your `ContactMail` class and `contactform.blade.php`.

Comment: it's not working :( I have call: Mail::to($adminEmail)->send(new ContactMail($message, $mailTitle, $email, $adminEmail));

Comment: and build: public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject($this->title)
                ->from($this->sender)
                ->to($this->adminMail)
                ->replyTo($this->sender)
                ->view('mail.contactform', ['message' => $this->message]);
    }

Comment: and template:@section('content')
{{ $message }}
@endsection - when I run my script I have error: htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /var/www/project/resources/views/mail/contactform.blade.php)

Comment: @trafficker I've updated my answer, check the new edit section